# Creating save/unsave post confirmation modal like in Reddit app?

Tags: swift

What's the best way to create a small pop-up/modal like on the Reddit app (please see link below for pic)? I've tried using UIAlertView but it's not very customizable. Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

[Screenshot of Reddit app's save "Post Saved!" confirmation modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqtT7.jpg)

Comment: Did my solution worked or need some more modifications ? if you are done with the required steps for this questions Kindly close this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something Like this

```
extension UIViewController
{
    func showNotificationView(message : String)
    {
        //base View
        let baseView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.height*0.15), width: self.view.frame.size.width-40, height: self.view.frame.size.height*0.08))
        baseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        baseView.clipsToBounds=true
        self.view.addSubview(baseView)

        //Image View
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "RM_3"))
        imageView.clipsToBounds=true
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: baseView.frame.size.width*0.2, height: baseView.frame.size.height)
        baseView.addSubview(imageView)

        //Label
        let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: baseView.frame.size.width*0.2+10, y: 0, width: baseView.frame.size.width, height: baseView.frame.size.height))
        textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textLabel.textAlignment = .left;
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)
        textLabel.text = message
        baseView.addSubview(textLabel)
    }
}
```

**How to Use**

```
 @IBAction func navigate(_ sender: Any) {
        self.showNotificationView(message: "hihihihh")
    }
```

**Output**

[image]