# Swift - response view in every view?

Tags: ios, swift, view, response

I've got a small question: is it possible somehow (without storyboard) to create a little view at the top of the screen (if there's a navigationbar, then under that), that displays errors / responses if needed?

Without creating views on every single viewController I made, just by code?

Or is there some extension you could recommend?

For example: "No Internet Connection"

[image]

Comment: You can use this library which supports the same functionality: https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages

Comment: I would recommend Whisper: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper

Comment: You can put it into your navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129636/6080920

**Code required**

```
extension UIViewController
{
    func showNotificationView(message : String)
    {
        //base View
        let baseView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.size.height-(self.view.frame.size.height*0.15), width: self.view.frame.size.width-40, height: self.view.frame.size.height*0.08))
        baseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        baseView.clipsToBounds=true
        self.view.addSubview(baseView)

        //Image View
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "RM_3"))
        imageView.clipsToBounds=true
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: baseView.frame.size.width*0.2, height: baseView.frame.size.height)
        baseView.addSubview(imageView)

        //Label
        let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: baseView.frame.size.width*0.2+10, y: 0, width: baseView.frame.size.width, height: baseView.frame.size.height))
        textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textLabel.textAlignment = .left;
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)
        textLabel.text = message
        baseView.addSubview(textLabel)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@IBAction func navigate(_ sender: Any) {
        self.showNotificationView(message: "hihihihh")
    }
```